# Two different definitions of $R_{ijkl}$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

By combining the equations
$$R_{ijk}{}^l=e^l(R_{ij}e_k)$$
and
$$R_{ijkl}= g_{lm}R_{ijk}{}^m$$
on page $197$ and $198$ of Lee's [Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-91755-9) I obtain
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
R_{ijkl}= g_{lm}R_{ijk}{}^m=g(e_l,e_m)e^m(R_{ij}e_k)=g(e_l,R_{ij}e_k)=g(R_{ij}e_k,e_l).
\end{equation}
This is consistent with $(2.2.48)$ in Gilkey's $2$nd edition of [Invariance theory](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203749791).

However, on page $34$ of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) (Getzler et al) and on page $14$ of Roe's [Elliptic Operators](https://doi.org/10.1201/b16418) we have the following definition:
$$R_{ijkl}:=g(e_i,R_{kl}e_j)$$
which is different from $(1)$, isn't it?

**Edit**: AFAIK we can use interchange symmetry and skew symmetry ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Symmetries_and_identities)) to obtain
$$g(e_l,R_{ij}e_k)=g(R_{ij}e_k,e_l)=g(R_{kl}e_i,e_j)=g(e_j,R_{kl}e_i)=-g(e_i,R_{kl}e_j)$$
and this shows that the two definitions are indeed different, right?

Comment: FWIW Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, 2.1,   p. 89, defines  the curvature to be $R(X,Y)= \nabla_Y\nabla_X- \nabla_X\nabla_Y+\nabla_{[X,Y]}$ (the opposite of 'expected') and then on page 90  adds "Let us remark also that a frequently encountered definition of curvature in the literature differs from the definition 2.1 by a sign."

Comment: In the end you have to decide which notation you want to use yourself and get used to deciphering the notation of each paper or book you read. I use the one used by Getzler et al and Roe. It indeed differs from Lee’s and Gilkey’s notation by a sign.

Comment: I definitely do not like Do Carmo’s backwards definition.

Comment: @Deane do you know the justification for Do Carmo's notation? Historical, perhaps?

Comment: not 'notation' - 'convention,' or 'definition'